# Can't we publish java serializable objects to kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

If I convert java object to byte[] , kafka consumes. But if i publish the java object directly, consumer iterator is not listening. My iterator is empty. Can't we do like this?

**pojo**

```
public class Test implements Serializable{
}
```

**producer**

```
public void sendTest(String topic, Test test) throws CoreException {

        Producer<String,  Test> producer = null;
        try {
            producer = new Producer<String,  Test>(producerConfig);
            KeyedMessage<String, Test> msg = new KeyedMessage<String, Test>(topic,  Test);

            producer.send(msg);
            System.out.println("producing ..");

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {
            if (producer != null)
                producer.close();
        }
    }
```

**Consumer**

```
ConsumerIterator<byte[], byte[]> itr = m_stream.iterator();
            while (itr.hasNext()) {
byte[] data = itr.next().message();
    System.out.println("Message received :" +data);
}
```

Comment: is there any exception in logs? Have you set serializer.class variable?

Comment: @Natalia i have defined as  "serializer.class=kafka.serializer.DefaultEncoder" .Looks like then i have to define my own serializer class.